# Oozie shell action issue while creating directories

Tags: oozie, bigdata

I am unable to add/delete any files or directories on HDFS from a shell script which I am executing from Oozie workflow.
The username is "scitest" and the hdfs path I am trying to edit/add/delete is
/user/scitest/.

In the shell script I am trying to delete a folder named test123456 from the path /user/scitest/.

**---------------Error from oozie log------------------**

```
429737-oozie-oozi-W@shell-node] Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]
2016-12-27 05:04:25,553  INFO ActionEndXCommand:520 - SERVER[vscihadoopvm2.manhdev.com] USER[scitest] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[shell.workflow] JOB[0000041-161208225429737-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000041-161208225429737-oozie-oozi-W@shell-node] ERROR is considered as FAILED for SLA
```

**---------shell-script(sample.sh) content----------**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "`date` hi" > output.log
hadoop fs -mkdir test123456
```

**-------job.properties---------**

```
nameNode=hdfs://vscihadoopvm1.manhdev.com:8020
jobTracker=vscihadoopvm2.manhdev.com:8050
master=yarn-cluster
#user.name=yarn
queueName=default
examplesRoot=oozietest
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/${examplesRoot}
```

**---workflow.xml---**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5" name="shell.workflow">
<start to="shell-node"/>
  <action name="shell-node">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.3">
      <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
      <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
      <configuration>
        <property>
          <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
          <value>${queueName}</value>
        </property>
      </configuration>
      <exec>sample.sh</exec>
      <file>sample.sh#sample.sh</file>
    </shell>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="kill"/>
  </action>
  <kill name="kill">
    <message>Error in Shell.Please refer the Oozie Logs</message>
  </kill>
  <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Comment: The error message does not seem relevant to me. I am able to execute the script. Also provide the complete path in the `file` tag of the shell action in workflow.xml. Thanks.

Comment: @YoungHobbit , thanks for your response..

Comment: @YoungHobbit , thank you for your response..I tried adding the complete hdfs path of the shell script but didn't help.. <file>/user/scitest/oozietest/sample.sh#sample.sh</file> but didn't help...gave the same error...could it be a permission problem..

Comment: `<file>${nameNode}/user/scitest/oozietest/sample.sh#sample.sh</file>`. Also please check your error message in the logs. Also is it getting launched with Mapper job or not. If yes, then check the logs into launched job. Thanks.

Comment: @YoungHobbit, I tried adding the namenode to the file location but didnt help..I tried to run the same code on Cloudera but I am facing the same issue...only thing which I changed to run on cloudera was to modify the resourcemanager port to 8032 and user.name=cloudera...I am still not able to delete or add any folder...I checked the logs from the 8088 http port and saw the oozie mr job has run successfully...I am missing some basic step due to which the folder is not getting created...can you help?

Comment: @YoungHobbit , can you share the code snippet which worked for you on a cloudera vm?

Comment: `oozie mr job has run successfully` it will be marked successful only. Please click on the job and check the link. I am tried in the HDP sandbox. Oozie shell example by replacing with shell commands. Thanks.

Comment: from the Oozie logs.. I see that this job has failed job_1482914210538_0010..when I logged in the resource manager logs...and checked the application_<job_id> (as its yarn)..it says successful..

Comment: below is the extract from the job_id logs...any idea?

Comment: >>> Invoking Shell command line now >>

Exit code of the Shell command 1
<<< Invocation of Shell command completed <<<


<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<

Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]

Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully

Oozie Launcher, uploading action data to HDFS sequence file: hdfs://localhost:8020/user/cloudera/oozie-oozi/0000010-161228003759090-oozie-oozi-W/shell-node--shell/action-data.seq

Oozie Launcher ends

Answer (score 0):

@Abhiroy, Maybe its better if you can check with which user your oozie action is getting executed. you can simply place 'id' without quotes in your sample shell script and run the workflow. Then you can trace the oozie job logs to see the container executer for your sample script that oozie is using. Then we can start tracing if you have any permission issues.