# how to use a shell-action from oozie to write to create a file in HDFS

Tags: cloudera, oozie, bigdata

I am invoking the below shell-action to invoke a shell script which writes an output to a file.
I have tried this on both IBM BigInsight and Cloudera but whenever I am trying to write to a new file in HDFS the job fails.

I checked the application/job id logs but had no info.
Is there any restriction to write to hdfs from a shell script.

---sample.sh---

```
hive -e "create t1(id int); insert into t1 values(1);"
hive -e "select * from t1;" > /user/cloudera/test123/t1_data.txt
```

--workflow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5" name="shell.workflow">
  <start to="shell-node"/>
    <action name="shell-node">
        <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <prepare>
               <delete path="test123"/>
               <mkdir path="test123"/>
            </prepare>

            <configuration>
                <property>
                                  <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                                  <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <exec>sample.sh</exec>
            <env-var>HADOOP_USER_NAME=cloudera</env-var>
            <file>hdfs://localhost:8020/user/cloudera/oozietest/sample.sh#sample.sh</file>
            <capture-output/>
        </shell>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
        <kill name="kill">
            <message>Error in Shell.Please refer the Oozie Logs</message>
         </kill>
<end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

--job.properties

```
nameNode=hdfs://localhost:8020
jobTracker=localhost:8032
master=yarn-cluster
user.name=cloudera
queueName=default
examplesRoot=oozietest
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/${examplesRoot}
```

Answer (score 1):

Oozie shell action doesn't work for Hive operations. Here you need to use Oozie Hive action.To work with Oozie Hive action you need to prepare `.sql` file where you wil put all your hive query, and then you need to schedule with Oozie workflow.

Please see below sample `workflow.xml` for Oozie Hive action.

```
<workflow-app name="oozie_hive_action" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
    <credentials>
        <credential name="hcat" type="hcat">
            <property>
                <name>hcat.metastore.uri</name>
                <value>${hcat_metastore_uri}</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>hcat.metastore.principal</name>
                <value>${hcat_metastore_principal}</value>
            </property>
        </credential>
    </credentials>
        <start to="Hive_action"/>
        <action name="hive-table-refresh" cred="hcat">
            <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
                <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
                <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
                <prepare>
                    <delete path="${jobOutputDir}"/>
                </prepare>
                <job-xml>/diretory/path/to/hive-site.xml</job-xml>
                <configuration>
                    <property>
                        <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                        <value>${queueName}</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>oozie.hive.defaults</name>
                        <value>/diretory/path/to/hive-site.xml</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>oozie.use.system.libpath</name>
                        <value>true</value>
                    </property>
                </configuration>
                <script>/project/hdfs/dir/to/scripts/hive_jobs.sql</script>
                <param>OutputDir=${jobOutputDir}</param>
                <file>/user/${userName}/${userName}.keytab#${userName}.keytab</file> <!-- If you are using kerberos authentiation -->
                <file>/project/hdfs/dir/to/scripts/hive_jobs.sql</file>
                <file>/project/hdfs/dir/to/properties/job.properties#job.properties</file>
            </hive>
            <ok to="end"/>
            <error to="kill"/>
        </action>
        <kill name="kill">
            <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
        </kill>
        <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Please visit [Oozie Hive Action Documentations](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/DG_HiveActionExtension.html) for more information about it.

Here credentail section is optional.

```
<credentials>
    <credential name="hcat" type="hcat">
        <property>
            <name>hcat.metastore.uri</name>
            <value>${hcat_metastore_uri}</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>hcat.metastore.principal</name>
            <value>${hcat_metastore_principal}</value>
        </property>
    </credential>
</credentials>
```

It can be used, if your clauster crequired an authenticated (typically via Kerberos).

If you clauter doesnot require Kerberos authenticated then remove `<credentials>` section and `<file>/user/${userName}/${userName}.keytab#${userName}.keytab</file>`

then replace `<action name="hive-table-refresh" cred="hcat">` with `<action name="hive-table-refresh">`

You can also visit [Oozie Action Authentication documentation](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_ActionAuthentication.html) to get more information about Authentication.

Here `hive-site.xml` is the site xml should present in `$HIVE_HOME/conf` folder.
`hive_jobs.sql` file contains the actual hive query. i.e. `use db_name;select * from table_name`.

Comment: thank you Sandeep for the detailed explanation..I really appreciate your help....Is there way I can create a file from a shell script run from a shell action node from Oozie... this is the question I had put on the forum...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41343318/oozie-shell-action-issue-while-creating-directories

Comment: Yes, you can create, delete file or directory on HDFS from Oozie shell action.You need to provide full HDFS Path of the script in `workflow.xml`. If you are unable to do so please check permission on that location.

Answer (score 0):

In your version of code, when you are referring to '/user/cloudera/test123/t1_data.txt', oozie looks for local FS path on the datanode which it is being executed and it maynot find it.

you can use below code to write onto HDFS directory from Hive table:

> hive -e "INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/user/cloudera/test123/t1' SELECT
>   * FROM t1;"

However, the best way to do is using Hive action of oozie to do this task unless you have some purpose that you should definetly use Shell action only. You can place the above Hive statement in your Hive action of oozie as well.

Comment: hi Deepak, thank you for your help..actually I tried the above but the challenge is that I need to refer the content of the file as a parameter for another hive query...  I need to read the text from the while above and use it as a parameter in a sqoop import "select * from xyz_table where date_time=${date_time} and $CONDITION...is there a way I can create/delete a while from a shell script running from Oozie...

Comment: .this is the related question I had put on the forum http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41343318/oozie-shell-action-issue-while-creating-directories